# How can I show "output change path" in a custom panel?

Tags: scripting

Hello I want make a blender addon to save images from blender but I want to change the default path.

I know right you can change the output path here.
[image]

I want to use that in my custom addon.
[image]

right know I can get the path string
by using

```
        row.label(text="Render Path " + bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
```

But I like to use the same row from the Output panel to change the path.
I want to use the same thing but in another panel is that possible ?

Answer (score 3):

**Put the property in your layout**

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
    layout.prop(scene.render, "filepath")
```

If you enable developer extras in preferences, can right click on any (just about) and "View Source".

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem so hopefully this will help.
You will need to create a class to hold your custom Property (the utility to make your path)

```
class RenderPathProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
   path: StringProperty(
       name="",
       description="Path to Directory",
       default="",
       maxlen=1024,
       subtype='DIR_PATH')
```

When registering this class also make the include the new property as part of the scene class:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RenderPathProperty)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_path = PointerProperty(type=RenderPathProperty)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RenderPathProperty)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_path
```

When making the Panel class, in the draw function, make sure to define a place where you call the property:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    col = row.column(align=True)
    col.prop(context.scene.my_path, "path", text="")
```

Let me know if this works out

Comment: You don't necessarily need a `PropertyGroup`... You can register your property directly eg. to the scene: `bpy.types.Scene.my_path = StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')` Also the question is: How to duplicate the existing *Output Path* property into a custom panel.